# Which one of these is correct?

Tags: ruby

Among the following formats which is correct not just syntax but as a practice as well ?

```
 DateTime.strptime((date[:month]+date[:year]),'%B %Y')
```

or

```
 DateTime.strptime((date[:month]+' '+date[:year]),'%B %Y')
```

or

```
 DateTime.strptime((date[:month]+date[:year]),'%B%Y')
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: what is the value of `date`?

Answer (score 2):

Ref [strptime](http://apidock.com/ruby/DateTime/strptime/class)

```
They both are correct as long as you giving correct values 
of 'date[:month]' & 'date[:year]'

1.9.3p327 :015 > DateTime.strptime("Mar 2010",'%B %Y')
 => Mon, 01 Mar 2010 00:00:00 +0000 
1.9.3p327 :016 > DateTime.strptime("Mar2010",'%B %Y')
 => Mon, 01 Mar 2010 00:00:00 +0000
```

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically, both `DateTime.strptime((date[:month]+' '+date[:year]),'%B %Y')` and `DateTime.strptime((date[:month]+date[:year]),'%B%Y')` are correct.

As a practice, the 2nd one is better as there is no point adding a `' '` and then parsing it out. Anyway, both will give the same output.